Can you flip a player you just traded for at will?
In the content on the internet about most games concerning American sports (football, basketball, baseball, ice hockey), you find rebuilds where most would get smaller assets to flip them as fast as possible to other teams to then get better assets.
I wonder if it is a reglementary acceptable possibility
Is there a rule in American sports, that you must wait x duration to trade out a player you just traded for?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
